# SelectOrDie - JQuery as directive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, plugins, angularjs-directive

I want to build http://vst.mn/selectordie/ as Directive in my angular application.I referred few samples, tried but I couldn't get it done.

```
var app = angular.module('selectordie', []);

app.directive('selectordie', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority:1,
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
      return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        $timeout(function() {
          element.find('select').selectOrDie({
            placeholder: attrs.label ? attrs.label : null,
            onChange: function() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue($(this).val());
            }
          });
        });
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          console.log(element.find('select').val(ngModel.$modelValue));
          element.find('select').val(ngModel.$modelValue);
          element.find('select option[value="' + ngModel.$modelValue + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
          element.find('select').selectOrDie('update');
        };
      }
    }
  };
});
```

When I call,

```
  angular.module('SSSample', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate','selectordie']); //
```

It was giving "selectordie is not a function". Not rendering page itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/Femina/6659mabm/

I tried as "E" , "C" too. Kindly guide me with STEP BY STEP way. So it will help me to build & customise other plugins. Also, I like to know , Is there any way to build "common plugin directive" , pass plugins as dynamically and customise if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using/understanding the `compile` method of directives correctly. A full blown `compile` method looks like this:

```
'compile': function (tElem, tAttrs) {

    return {

        'pre': function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){

        },

        'post': function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){

        }
    }
}
```

You can execute logic in the `compile` method and  `pre` and `post` link methods. All get fired in successive order but there's a big difference between all of them. A great write up on the matter can be found on the link below but the important thing to know is that you want to access `iElem` (the element that the directive is on) when it (and all of it's children) is fully processed and that's in the `post` link method. Thing is that using the `post` link method is the same as omitting the `compile` method all together and using the `link` method of your directive definition:

```
'link': function (scope, elem, attrs) {

}
```

So when you want to initialize the selectordie plugin on the element you'll need to so in the directive's `link` method (or in the compile's `post` method):

```
'link': function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    $(elem).selectOrDie();
}
```

Here's the link to the writeup i was talking about, it's really comprehensive and to really get a good picture of the concept you'll need to read it in it's entirety. I could quote some important parts but that won't do it justice. It's really a recommended read if really want to write good directives:

http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

Below here is a working example. Note that i scrapped the `restrict` and `require` definitions because the aren't necessary for showing a working directive for you to start working with. I'de really recommend you also read the following link, the angular guide on directives. It will learn you what each definition in your directive is for, so you can decide when to use them and why instead of using them because some tutorial says so:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```js
angular.module('App', ['selectordie']);

angular.module('App').controller('Controller', [
             '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.options = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Alpha'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bravo'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Charlie'
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Delta'
        }];
        $scope.selected = $scope.options[0];
    }
]);

angular.module('selectordie', []);

angular.module('selectordie').directive('selectordie', [
    function () {
        return {
            'priority': 1,
            'link': function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                $(iElem).selectOrDie();
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Angular 1.5.0</title>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/vestman/Select-or-Die/master/_src/selectordie.css" />
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/vestman/Select-or-Die/master/_src/selectordie.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Controller">
        <select selectordie name="select" id="select" ng-model="selected" ng-options="option.name for option in options">
        </select>
        {{selected}}
    </body>
</html>
```

On your question regarding a common plugin directive, i don't think that's it's possible and wouldn't recommend it even if it was. Treat each case separately, so you have tailored solutions. If you would do something like that, when needing something simple, you would carry the bloat of being prepared for something complicated.

Hope that helps, good luck with your project